# Processing.js : reading information from file

Tags: html, processing, processing.js

I have a processing sketch in which I read some coordinates from a file:

```
float[][] points = new float[243][3];

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
  background(255);
  camera(100, 50, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0);
  String lines[] = loadStrings("1xd3CoordsKnot");

  for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String[] list = split(lines[i], " ");
    float x = Float.parseFloat(list[0]);
    float y = Float.parseFloat(list[1]);
    float z = Float.parseFloat(list[2]);
    points[i][0] = x;
    points[i][1] = y;
    points[i][2] = z;
  }
 }

void draw() {
  background(50);
  lights();

  //the 3d lines here
  for (int i = 0; i < 242; i++) {
    line(points[i][0],points[i][1],points[i][2],points[i+1][0],points[i+1][1],points[i+1][2]);
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
  }

}
```

It works perfectly fine when run within processing. I am trying to embed it into a web page. The lines are not drawn in that case. The javascript console gave me an error saying that the files from which the coordinates are read is not found in the root directory of the html file, so I copied it there. But now it does not display the sketch at all, and gives me the following error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Float`.

The `html` is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="js/processing.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="pde/1xd3.pde"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
parseFloat(list[0]);
```

instead of

```
Float.parseFloat();
```

It should do the job! :)

Comment: This got rid of the error. However, the lines drawn are stuck at the upper left corner.

Comment: what do you mean by "stuck"? are they small or just a point at `0, 0` Maybe your lines are wrongly parsed, if you could share a sample of your file it could help. And maybe you could open a new question because the `Float` issue you was experiencing has gone! :)

Comment: That's what I was thinking. They are not stuck at `0,0`, but they are clustered at one corner. This was for a project, and I decided not to bother with it due to insufficient time. Thank you for you help :)

Comment: with this solution, the sketch no longer works in Java mode, so we're still left with broken code. The real solution here is to use Processing, not "Java" or "JavaScript": Processing has its own float conversion function already, just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Java API calls for this, use Processing's own API so that your sketch doesn't break when you run it in "not a JVM" (remember that Processing *is* a language, it's not "a subset of Java", it's a language that simply compiles to Java with minimal rewrites, so if you want portable code, use Processing, not "something supported by the interpreter you are using").

Processing has its own float parsing function, simply called [`float()`](https://processing.org/reference/floatconvert_.html):

```
String a = "3.52312";
float b = float(a); // b is now the number 3.52312
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code still doesn't work, though. There probably is something else going wrong. I excluded some parts of the code in the original question, because the error was strictly about the `float` conversion. I'm trying to do some `camera()` tricks that for some reason don't work in `processing.js`. I suppose I need to post it as a separate question.